# Import compose sample projects to android studio version 4.2

Tags: android, import, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to import [compose sample projects](https://github.com/android/compose-samples), but I'm facing this error:

```
Invalid injected android support version '202.7660.26.42.7322048', expected to be of the form 'w.x.y.z'
```

The android studio is currently updated to its newest version 4.2.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Use Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 15. More info: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The version `202.7660.26.42.7322048` is

```
Android Studio 4.2
Build #AI-202.7660.26.42.7322048, built on April 29, 2021
```

As suggested in the current (`1.0.0-beta08`) [official setup](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup) of compose you should use the Android Studio in the beta channel:

```
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Beta 03
```

Answer (score 6):

### Two methods to resolve this issue:

1. Update Android Studio to canary channel 2021.1.1 Canary 1(AI-203.7717.56.2111.7361063) which includes the fix
2. If you wish to remain in Android Studio stable channel Build #AI-202.7660.26.42.7351085, built on May 10, 2021 then you will need to

> Open Project Structure dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) and select Android Gradle plugin version to 4.2.1 ( >4.2.1 has this bug till version 7.1.0-alpha01) and Gradle version to 7.0.2.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Feature works fine on below version of Android studio.[image]