# Issue with importing a code in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am working on someone's else app, which I have cloned from another repository. While running the application, I keep on getting an error message.
The error message which I get is the following:-

```
Invalid injected android support version '202.7660.26.42.7351085', 
expected to be of the form 'w.x.y.z'
```

The system is running on `OpenJDK version "1.8.0_292"`
The Android Studio is currently on its version 4.2.1

I tried upgrading the Android Studio, to the Canary Channel, but the problem seems to still exist.

**Update**
The problem is solved, just upgrade to `Arctic Fox(2020.3.1)` and it works like a charm. The problem was, the file had dependencies, which were incompatible with my machine. So it didn't work out well initially.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import compose sample projects to android studio version 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67447249/import-compose-sample-projects-to-android-studio-version-4-2)

Comment: @dominicoder No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe that android project is using some feature that is still under development and not released yet

Answer (score 0):

Try to Update Android Studio, this problem appear on older versions. hope this will work

Comment: It is updated to the latest stable version. Are you talking about upgrading it to the Canary channel?